# Getting NZEC error code in codechef

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

https://www.codechef.com/COLG2016/problems/CL16BA

Chef has recently acquired a job as a professor, but is rather disappointed in his students after evaluating their scores on a test. Chef has N students, and he has a list of marks of all the students, where the ith student has scored Ai marks. The minimum marks required to pass the test is M. If the topper scores less than M, Chef has decided to quit his job. Can you help Chef find out the score of the topper of the test?

Input:
The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows. The first line of each test case contains the number of Chef's students N and the minimum pass marks M. The second line of each test case contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, ..., AN denoting the scores of the students

Output:
For each test case, output a single line containing an integer which is the maximum score in the test if that score is not less than M. If it is less then M, print "RESIGN" (without quotes).

my code:

```
line1=int(raw_input())
i=0
while(i<line1):
    marks=[]
    line2 = map(int, raw_input().split())
    line3 = map(int, raw_input().split())
    for j in range(len(line3)):
        marks.append(line3[j])
    if(max(marks)<line2[1]):
        print "RESIGN"
    else:
        print max(marks)
```

On submitting my programm, I am getting NZEC runtime error on codechef. This is my first attempt at competitve programming. Any helps/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just increment the *i* counter at last after the print `max(marks)`. See the code below:

```
if(max(marks)<line2[1]):
    print "RESIGN"
else:
    print max(marks)
i=i+1
```

Comment: While that isn't your code: any comments on appending elements from `line3` to `marks`? (Welcome to SO. That one sentence in your answer may be easier to grasp, still, if you make code parts like `i` and `print max(marks)` stand out. And use blanks after punctuation marks where appropriate.)

Comment: you have initialize i and using in while loop whether you are incrementing that  i ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
try:
  #working code
except Exception:
   pass
```

If the "Exception" does not work then you can try with different error exception name.
Try and catch exception for java code.